# How do you create multiple buttons in a ListView that are independent of each other?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have setup a Firestore database in which I have a collection 'products'. I use a ListView builder to print them out on ListTiles.
I have also created leading "checkmark" IconButtons that appear for all ListTiles.
My goal is to be able to press whichever of these checkmark buttons and change their color independently. Currently, all of the checkmark buttons change color when you press one of them.
I don't know how to achieve this and would appreciate some help.

```
class HomeScreenProductList extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreenProductList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreenProductList> createState() => _HomeScreenProductListState();
}

class _HomeScreenProductListState extends State<HomeScreenProductList> {
  final CollectionReference _productsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _products = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('products')
      .orderBy('product-name')
      .snapshots();

  deleteProduct(id) async {
    await _productsCollection.doc(id).delete();
  }

  Color tileColor = const Color.fromARGB(100, 158, 158, 158);
  Color iconColor = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _products,
        builder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
        ) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text('Loading data');
          }

          final productData = snapshot.requireData;

          return ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
            itemCount: productData.size,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: iconColor),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (iconColor != Colors.green) {
                              iconColor = Colors.green;
                            } else {
                              iconColor = Colors.red;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  tileColor: tileColor,
                  shape: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1, color: Color.fromARGB(120, 220, 220, 220))),
                  title: Text('${productData.docs[index]['product-name']}'),
                  textColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                  trailing: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("Delete Button Pressed");
                          deleteProduct(snapshot.data?.docs[index].id);
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Full Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const ShoppingListApp());
}

class ShoppingListApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShoppingListApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HomeScreenAppBar();
  }
}

class HomeScreenAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeScreenAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final CollectionReference _products =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');

  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  String? _productName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(245, 244, 253, 255),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            iconSize: 20,
            color: Colors.black,
            splashColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {
              print("Settings Button Pressed");
            },
          ),
          title: TextFormField(
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontFamily: 'Raleway'),
            controller: _controller,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Color.fromARGB(245, 244, 253, 255))),
                focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
                hintText: 'Enter product',
                hintStyle:
                    TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(200, 255, 255, 255))),
            onChanged: (value) {
              _productName = value;
            },
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              iconSize: 24,
              color: Colors.black,
              splashColor: Colors.white,
              onPressed: () {
                if (_controller.text == '') {
                  return;
                } else {
                  _products
                      .add({'product-name': _productName, 'isbought': false})
                      .then(
                          (value) => print('New Product "$_productName" Added'))
                      .catchError((error) => print(
                          'Failed To Add Product "$_productName": $error'));
                  _controller.clear();
                }
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: const HomeScreenProductList());
  }
}

class HomeScreenProductList extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreenProductList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreenProductList> createState() => _HomeScreenProductListState();
}

class _HomeScreenProductListState extends State<HomeScreenProductList> {
  final CollectionReference _productsCollection =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products');

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _products = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('products')
      .orderBy('product-name')
      .snapshots();

  deleteProduct(id) async {
    await _productsCollection.doc(id).delete();
  }

  Color tileColor = const Color.fromARGB(100, 158, 158, 158);
  Color iconColor = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _products,
        builder: (
          BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
        ) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text('Loading data');
          }

          final productData = snapshot.requireData;

          return ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16.0),
            itemCount: productData.size,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: iconColor),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (iconColor != Colors.green) {
                              iconColor = Colors.green;
                            } else {
                              iconColor = Colors.red;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  tileColor: tileColor,
                  shape: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                          width: 1, color: Color.fromARGB(120, 220, 220, 220))),
                  title: Text('${productData.docs[index]['product-name']}'),
                  textColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
                  trailing: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print("Delete Button Pressed");
                          deleteProduct(snapshot.data?.docs[index].id);
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single variable `iconColor` to change all items. That's why all items are getting effected by changing any of it.  You can create a `List<int>` to hold  selected index
, `List<YourModelClass>` or on your model create another bool variable `bool icChecked = false`.

This approach is holding selected index on state class.

On state class(`_HomeScreenProductListState`) create

```dart
List<int> selectedIndex = []
```

And on item tap event

```dart
icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: selectedIndex.contains(index)?mySelectedColor:unSelectedColor)
onPressed: () {
  if (selectedIndex.contains(index)) {
    selectedIndex.remove(index);
  } else {
    selectedIndex.add(index);
  }

  setState(() {});
},
```

`mySelectedColor` and `unSelectedColor` are two `Color` objects based on your need.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using IconColor as a singular global variable. What you could possible do instead is create a boolean list for every data in the `ProductData`

```
List<bool> iconColorList = List<bool>.filled(ProductData.size, false);
```

and in the listview builder

```
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: iconColorList[index] ? Colors.green : Colors.false),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (iconColorList[index]) {
                              iconColorList[index] = false;
                            } else {
                              iconColorList[index] = true;
                            }
                          });
                        },
                      )
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason all checkmarks change color is that you are saving the color in `iconColor` and then assigning that color to all the IconButtons.

This happens in the following lines of code:

```
  IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: iconColor),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        if (iconColor != Colors.green) {
          iconColor = Colors.green;
        } else {
          iconColor = Colors.red;
        }
      });
    },
  )
```

To achieve the desired behaviour you should save the *state* of every single checkmark.
Take a look at [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

All `List` elements are referencing the same `Color` variable. So, when that variable changes, all associated elements change accordingly.

I suggest you create separate widget for your `itemBuilder`. That way you can track each element state internally. Here's the example:

```
class HomeScreenProductList extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreenProductList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomeScreenProductList> createState() => _HomeScreenProductListState();
}

class _HomeScreenProductListState extends State<HomeScreenProductList> {
  // Sample data structure
  final productData = [
    {'id': '1', 'product-name': 'Product 1'},
    {'id': '2', 'product-name': 'Product 2'},
    {'id': '3', 'product-name': 'Product 3'},
    {'id': '4', 'product-name': 'Product 4'},
    {'id': '5', 'product-name': 'Product 5'},
  ];

  void _deleteProduct(String id) {
    productData.removeWhere((el) => el['id'] == id);
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: productData.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final product = productData[index];

            // Separate widget for each List element
            return ProductListViewTile(
              key: Key('$index'),
              product: product,
              deleteProduct: _deleteProduct,
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}


// Extract List element to a separate widget and track it's state locally
class ProductListViewTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProductListViewTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.product,
    required this.deleteProduct,
  }) : super(key: key);

  // Product to display
  final Map<String, String> product;
  // Callback method
  final void Function(String id) deleteProduct;

  @override
  State<ProductListViewTile> createState() => _ProductListViewTileState();
}

class _ProductListViewTileState extends State<ProductListViewTile> {
  Color iconColor = Colors.red;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.check, color: iconColor),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  if (iconColor != Colors.green) {
                    iconColor = Colors.green;
                  } else {
                    iconColor = Colors.red;
                  }
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        tileColor: const Color.fromARGB(100, 158, 158, 158),
        shape: const UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color.fromARGB(120, 220, 220, 220))),
        title: Text(widget.product['product-name']!),
        textColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
              color: Colors.red,
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(),
              onPressed: () {
                print("Delete Button Pressed");
                widget.deleteProduct(widget.product['id']!);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```